# Define an arbitrary number and variety of arguments

Tags: r

I have a problem and I don't know how to resolve it. When I define a function and determine its arguments, I would like to define an arbitrary number of some argument. For example, I would like to create a function (custom density) and I would like to put many vectors of values for which the density is desired.

A conventional way is something like this

```
dens_cust<- function( vector , ... other arguments desired ...)
```

In this case, my function will plot only one density, but I would like to plot any desired number of vectors.

Is some simple solution?

Comment: If the answer below doesn't immediately make sense to you, it's probably the best route to read the docs, e.g., this copy online: https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with `...` arguments. For instance, if you wanted to be passed an arbitrary number of vectors in addition to two arguments `arg1` and `arg2`, you could do something like:

```
dens_cust <- function(arg1, arg2, ...) {
  vecs <- list(...)
  # "vecs" is a list of the passed vectors; process each however you want
}
```

As a simple example, you could grab and return `a` times the mean of each passed vector plus `b` with something like:

```
dens_cust <- function(a, b, ...) {
  vecs <- list(...)
  a * sapply(vecs, mean) + b
}
dens_cust(2, 3, 1:3, 4:10)
# [1]  7 17
```

If you instead had some plotting function `plot_dens` that you wanted to apply to each vector, you could use:

```
dens_cust <- function(...) {
  vecs <- list(...)
  for (v in vecs) {
    plot_dens(v)
  }
}
```